# Opening disk device file for write access on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, posix, iokit

I'm trying to make a subtle modification to the partition table of a disk on the Mac; in particular, I need to change the type of a partition. `diskutil` doesn't support this, so I can't use it. It works fine (e.g. via a modified `gpt` command-line utility) if the disk isn't in use. If it is, it fails when opening the device file:

```
int fd = open("/dev/disk1", O_RDWR);
```

`fd` is -1 and `errno` indicates the error "resource busy".

I realise I can reboot the machine from a different drive, modify the original disk from there, then boot back. This is, however, not exactly easy to automate/reliable from inside my application. Besides, `diskutil` has no problem editing the partition table of the live device, and neither has the bootcamp installer.

Is there a known way to do this? Worst case, I can try to do it in the kernel, but kexts aren't really designed for doing one-off things, and what I need to do is really quite conceptually simple in userspace but quite hard in the kernel.

Any ideas?

**Note:** I'm running everything with `sudo`, so it should not be a permissions problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the source for fdisk?

Comment: fdisk doesn't actually work on any mac I've tested. It attempts to open a file `/usr/standalone/i386/boot0` which doesn't exist. Even apart from that, it doesn't seem to do anything clever.

Comment: OK, so if not fdisk, then the freebsd equivalent (which I'm guessing Apple frontends for their disk utility)

Comment: Intel Macs use the GUID partitioning scheme by default, hence my experiments with the `gpt` utility, which has its origins in BSD. `diskutil` does not seem to be a frontend for `gpt`, however, and as I mentioned, `gpt` doesn't actually work. Source for `diskutil` is not available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How Apple does it

After some sleuthing with `otool` and a disassembler, I determined that Apple's `diskutil` uses some private frameworks to do the job. (I looked at the command-line version, but the feature set and status/error messages of the GUI **Disk Utility** match it so closely, I doubt there is a difference) In particular, the Objective-C `DiskManagement.framework` contains classes and methods that map 1:1 to `diskutil` commands. A lot of error messages seem to come out of the `MediaKit.framework`, which isn't Objective-C based, so its API isn't visible right there in `otool`.

Briefly looking at the disassembly of some of the functions, it seems that Mach Ports and *MIG* are used heavily. I have no idea how deep the rabbit hole of reverse engineering that goes, and whether it leads anywhere useful. After all, the `DiskManagement.framework` seems to do exactly what `diskutil` does, and no more, so that doesn't include direct editing of the partition table. Even if I figured out how it does it under the hood, that may not help me fix my problem.

#### How I'm doing it

So, to avoid wasting any more time on activities with questionable chances of success, I ended up doing it via a kernel extension, just what I was trying to avoid. I basically built a general `IOService` subclass along with an `IOUserClient` companion subclass. This exposes some methods for replacing an existing partition table with a new one to user space processes running as root. It searches for the `IOMedia` object corresponding to the device name and with some trickery, does the read/write operations directly on that. I pass the old partition table to it so it can verify that it is indeed updating the right thing. On the user-space side, I modified the `gpt` utility to use the user-space I/O Kit libraries to talk to the kext. I only temporarily load the kext for making the changes and then unload it again. It took me the best part of 2 days but it works well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the raw disk device - in your case that would be `/dev/rdisk1`. Also, obviously, you'll need to be `root`.

Comment: I get "resource busy" with both `rdisk` or `disk`. It works with both for disks that aren't in use. And yes, I'm using `sudo` (otherwise I'd be getting a permission error, not "resource busy").

Comment: Allright, then simply make sure you unmount all volumes on that disk. If it is your boot disk (I shudder to think ;)) then you may want to boot off the OS X DVD.

Comment: Which disk it is is up to the user, and yeah, the main boot disk will be a popular choice. This is all connected to a (kernel) driver that is installed alongside. The driver won't load until the partition type matches, so I'd like to avoid writing *another* kernel module just for repartitioning. Looks like I'll have to, though.